# Getting error when using Oracle imp command to import dmp file

Tags: oracle, import

I am importing a dmp file using the following command:

```
imp user/pass file=file.dmp log=logfile.log full=y ignore=y destroy=y
```

I get the following errors:

```
. . importing table                "MESSAGE_BOARD"
IMP-00058: ORACLE error 22993 encountered
ORA-22993: specified input amount is greater than actual source amount
IMP-00028: partial import of previous table rolled back: 219638 rows rolled back
. . importing table       "MESSAGE_BOARD_ARCHIVES"
IMP-00058: ORACLE error 22993 encountered
ORA-22993: specified input amount is greater than actual source amount
IMP-00028: partial import of previous table rolled back: 2477960 rows rolled back
```

I have tried increasing the tablespace size and adding a second datafile to no avail. I'm a total newb at Oracle so any help will be appreciated. Googled this for hours and still can't come up with a solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Basically, your first step should be to try specifying a larger buffer (one large enough to hold your LOB).  And, so you're not surprised, this operation can take many, many hours (or even days) depending on the size of the import.

And, IIRC, this error can also be thrown if your import version is less than your export version... so check that, if moar buffer doesn't fix this.

If that fails, you'll need to provide moar details.

---

### ORA-22993: specified input amount is greater than actual source amount

> *Cause:  (1) For LOB write, the amount of data received is different from the amount that was indicated would be sent.  (2) For LOB copy and loadfromfile, the end of the source LOB/FILE value was reached before the specified input amount was copied/loaded.
>
> *Action: (1) will happen when using OCI's piecewise mechanism with polling or with a callback function.  Modify the code either to send the amount specified or to pass 0 as the input amount so that any amount of data can be sent.  (2) will happen if the specified input amount is too large for the source LOB/FILE given the starting source offset.  Either decrease the starting source offset, or decrease the amount to copy/load.